# On button click, select a sibling element with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="hidden">44</div>
  <input type="submit" id="btnAddCommentForAnswer" value="Add Comment" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAddCommentForAnswer').click(function () {
            alert(XXX);
        });

    });
  </script>    
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="hidden">12</div>
  <input type="submit" id="btnAddCommentForAnswer" value="Add Comment" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnAddCommentForAnswer').click(function () {
            alert(XXX)
        });

    });
  </script>  
</div>
```

what code should I put at XXX to get the content of the div with class=hidden when i press the  button at the same div with class=item?

If you click the first button you should get 44, and for clicking the second button you get 12.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`id's` are meant to be unique; you may wish to consider changing the `id` to a `class`.
With that in place, you could use a script like the following to achieve what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnAddCommentForAnswer').click(function() {
        alert($(this).siblings('.hidden').text());
    });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nNSHT/1/)

Also, you don't *need* to have two script tags in your script! This one script wrapped in `<script>` tags is all that is necessary :)

Answer (score 1):

Haven't tried but this should work:

```
$(this).closest('div').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need not repeat the javascript code multiple times. Also, you cannot use id in jquery as the buttons have same id.
Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/t8XJZ/ which might solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this is more useful for you...

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.item').each(function(){
         $(this).find("#btnAddCommentForAnswer").click(function () {
            alert($(this).prev(".hidden").text())
        });
    });
 });
```

html:

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="hidden">44</div>
  <input type="submit" id="btnAddCommentForAnswer" value="Add Comment" />  
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="hidden">12</div>
  <input type="submit" id="btnAddCommentForAnswer" value="Add Comment" />
</div>
```